# Raspberry Pi 3 - internal Wifi wont connect to network

Tags: raspbian, wifi, connection, pi-3, troubleshooting

i'm rather new to Linux and all that, in fact the Raspberry Pi 3 i just got is the first Linux-only machine i ever had, running the latest version of Raspbian .. so here's my problem:

I'm trying to use the integrated wifi adapter to establish a connection to my network / the interhet.

I do see my network showing up and i can try to connect to it, but it keeps either doing nothing (if i use the GUI thingie in the top right corner of the screen [sorry, i'm sure it has a propper name but i couldnt see any]) or it sais that the authentication failed when i try it with wpa_gui

Now here are my specs, i hope i get everything in there that is needed:

`ifconfig -a` says:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:6e:78:19  
      inet addr:192.168.0.163  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: 2a02:810a:11c0:2c8c:dfe1:d49f:7f8c:a4a1/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::eac9:60d9:4260:247c/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:8277 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7779 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:6894047 (6.5 MiB)  TX bytes:1298763 (1.2 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:136 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:136 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:11472 (11.2 KiB)  TX bytes:11472 (11.2 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:3b:2d:4c  
      BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:517 errors:0 dropped:517 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:30 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:165242 (161.3 KiB)  TX bytes:5325 (5.2 KiB)'
```

my `etc/network/interfaces` file i modified quite a few times already, trying out several things, currently its looking like this:

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
auto wlan0
iface eth0 inet manual
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface default inet dhcp
```

and the `etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` has this here:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="MySSID"
    psk="MyPsk"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=TKIP
    auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

The network i am trying to connect to is WPA2 PSK encrypted with TKIP, my only guess here is that i have to make some settings either in Raspbian's `wpa_supplicant.conf` or in my router to let the two of them communicate with each other?

Or am i missing something totally obvious here?

I would also be grateful for hints on what tools i can use under Linux to figure this problem out and see where what goes wrong :)

Thanks a lot in advance and sorry if i messed up any english ;)

Comment: You are using obsolete settings. If you unplugged the Ethernet it may work, but you would be better to use the recommended settings. See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: I'm getting a little worried about my Pi 3, now that I'm seeing so many internal wifi questions about it...

Comment: @Milliways thanks a lot for pointing out that i had obsolete settings, the tutorial you linked was very helpful, it could well be that i couldnt have solved it without it :)

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Pretty sure he just meant "says", I submitted an edit to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem.

First I updated my settings as suggested in the link that Miliways provided in a comment in my original answer.

That alone didn't solve it, what I actually had to do is change the configurations in my router:

The WiFi was set to WPA2/WPA -> I changed that to WPA2 only and now I can finally connect to the network without problems.

If there are configs that I would need to adjust in order to make WiFi work with WPA2/WPA settings in the router, I would be glad if anyone could provide these, I couldn't find anything considering that on the internet.

Comment: Worked for me too.

Comment: Worked for me as well. I found out how to make it work with mixed WPA2/WPA. I had to edit `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and change `CCMP` to `CCMP TKIP` in both the `pairwise=` and `group=` settings.

Comment: @PedroGimeno Could you please post a sample? I'm new to this and I don't see any pairwise setting and my group= setting is set to netdev, not CCMP. Thanks!

Comment: See `man wpa_supplicant.conf`. In the EXAMPLES section the first example has two `network=` sections; the second one uses what I say above for `pairwise` and `group`. Note it's the `group` inside `network` that you need to change or add, not the `GROUP` at the top.

Answer (score 1):

I've had problems before with using a pre-shared key, especially when I forgot to escape characters that needed to be escaped. Characters that may need to be escaped would be (among others):

`{}\[]<>?;~@"`

You escape a character by adding a '\' before it, so for example if your key was:

`P@ssword"!`

You would escape it like:

`P\@ssword\"\!`

Likewise, if you needed the character `\` in your password, you would escape it by prefixing like `\\`.

In this case, you haven't shared the key (good!), but have you made sure that it's properly escaped? If possible, could you change it to a key that's only alpha-numeric and try for troubleshooting purposes?

I don't see anything in the configuration that you've provided that points to any other configuration issue.

Comment: oh that is a really good tip, i did not know that you had to escape such characters in a PSK, however, mine only consists of upper and lowercase characters and numbers. but thanks for looking into the config as well, im happy that i didnt mess it up with my changes atleast :)

Comment: What about `&` and `*`, do those need to be escaped?